# deep learning image classifier architecture configuration

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I was looking at this tutorial on Deep Learning with Python, TensorFlow, and Keras tutorial and got these codes

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2

DATADIR = "C:/Users/Acer/imagerec/MRI"

CATEGORIES = ["yes", "no"]

for category in CATEGORIES:
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img) ,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        plt.imshow(img_array, cmap='gray')


        break
    break
print(img_array)
print(img_array.shape)

IMG_SIZE = 224

new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
plt.imshow(new_array, cmap='gray')


training_data = []

def create_training_data():
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
                training_data.append([new_array, class_num])
            except Exception as e:
                pass


create_training_data()

print(len(training_data))

import random

random.shuffle(training_data)
for sample in training_data[:10]:
    print(sample[1])

X = []
y = []
for features, label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)

X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)

import pickle

pickle_in = open("X.pickle","rb")
X = pickle.load(pickle_in)



pickle_in = open("y.pickle","rb")
y = pickle.load(pickle_in)

X = X/255.0

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=15, epochs=20, validation_split=0.1)

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
pred = model.predict(X)
pred = np.round(pred)

conf = confusion_matrix(y, pred)

import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(conf, annot=True)

plt.show()
```

so running these codes gave me good results with a 76.9% validation accuracy what i needed to do was to change the model of this code into VGG16,VGG19 and mobilenet but i dont know how to import a pretrained model so i decided to make my own model and train that so i looked at the architecture of VGG16 and VGG19 i looked at how many conv and maxpooling and came up with this code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2

DATADIR = "C:/Users/Acer/imagerec/EDA"

CATEGORIES = ["yes", "no"]

for category in CATEGORIES:
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img) ,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        plt.imshow(img_array, cmap='gray')
        plt.show()

        break
    break
print(img_array)
print(img_array.shape)

IMG_SIZE = 224

new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
plt.imshow(new_array, cmap='gray')
plt.show()

training_data = []

def create_training_data():
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
                training_data.append([new_array, class_num])
            except Exception as e:
                pass


create_training_data()

print(len(training_data))

import random

random.shuffle(training_data)
for sample in training_data[:10]:
    print(sample[1])

X = []
y = []
for features, label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)

X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)

import pickle

pickle_in = open("X.pickle","rb")
X = pickle.load(pickle_in)



pickle_in = open("y.pickle","rb")
y = pickle.load(pickle_in)

X = X/255.0

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
padding='same'
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
padding='same'
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 1)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
padding='same'
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
padding='same'
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 1)))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
padding='same'
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
padding='same'
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
padding='same'
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 1)))

model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
padding='same'
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
padding='same'
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
padding='same'
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 1)))

model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
padding='same'
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
padding='same'
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
padding='same'
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 1)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=15, epochs=1, validation_split=0.1)

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
pred = model.predict(X)
pred = np.round(pred)

conf = confusion_matrix(y, pred)

import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(conf, annot=True)

plt.show()
```

but running this always gave me a val accuracy of 57.69% in any epoch am i doing something wrong? or did i do everything wrong?

edit
so i used a pretrained model now

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2

DATADIR = "C:/Users/Acer/imagerec/MRI"

CATEGORIES = ["yes", "no"]

for category in CATEGORIES:
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img) ,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        plt.imshow(img_array, cmap='gray')


        break
    break
print(img_array)
print(img_array.shape)

IMG_SIZE = 224

new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
plt.imshow(new_array, cmap='gray')


training_data = []

def create_training_data():
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
                training_data.append([new_array, class_num])
            except Exception as e:
                pass


create_training_data()

print(len(training_data))

import random

random.shuffle(training_data)
for sample in training_data[:10]:
    print(sample[1])

X = []
y = []
for features, label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)

X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)

import pickle

pickle_in = open("X.pickle","rb")
X = pickle.load(pickle_in)



pickle_in = open("y.pickle","rb")
y = pickle.load(pickle_in)

X = X/255.0


def input_shape(args):
    pass


from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense

vgg = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(), pooling='avg')
x = vgg.output
x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(vgg.input, x)
model.summary()

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
pred = model.predict(X)
```

and got this error

```
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, None, None, 3)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 64)    1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 64)    36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 64)    0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 128)   73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 128)   147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 128)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 256)   295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 256)   590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 256)   590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 256)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 512)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 512)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d_1 ( (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 513       
=================================================================
Total params: 14,715,201
Trainable params: 14,715,201
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Acer/PycharmProjects/condas/UwU.py", line 95, in <module>
    pred = model.predict(X)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda3\envs\condas\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1441, in predict
    x, _, _ = self._standardize_user_data(x)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda3\envs\condas\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 579, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda3\envs\condas\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 145, in standardize_input_data
    str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (None, None, 3) but got array with shape (50, 50, 1)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: https://neurohive.io/en/popular-networks/vgg16/
this is the architecture of the VGG16 that I followed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a keras sequential model, only the first layer needs to know the `input_shape` it should expect, in your case its `Conv2D` layer. Also, there's no point in adding multiple `Dense` layers with sigmoid activation.

Refer this

```
model = Sequential([
Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape, padding='same', activation='relu'),
Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)),
Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',),
MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)),
Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',),
Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',),
Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',),
MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)),
Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',),
Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',),
Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',),
MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)),
Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',),
Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',),
Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',),
MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)),
Flatten(),
Dense(4096, activation='relu'),
Dense(4096, activation='relu'),
Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
```

Alternatively, you could use pretrained VGG model from keras applications.

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense

vgg = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(), pooling='avg')
x = vgg.output
x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(vgg.input, x)
model.summary()
```

Comment: hiya tnx for helping out i got this error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Acer/PycharmProjects/condas/UwU.py", line 85, in <module>
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda3\envs\condas\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda3\envs\condas\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\convolutional.py", line 484, in __init__
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda3\envs\condas\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\convolutional.py", line 105, in __init__
    super(_Conv, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda3\envs\condas\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 163, in __init__
    batch_size,) + tuple(kwargs['input_shape'])
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

Comment: but im trying out the pretrained model now

Comment: got this Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Acer/PycharmProjects/condas/UwU.py", line 97, in <module>
    model.fit(X, y, batch_size=15, epochs=1, validation_split=0.1)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda3\envs\condas\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1154, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda3\envs\condas\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 579, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')

Comment: File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda3\envs\condas\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 145, in standardize_input_data
    str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (None, None, 3) but got array with shape (50, 50, 1)

Comment: Your image size should be (50,50,3). Try to edit this  X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)

Comment: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (None, None, 3) but got array with shape (50, 50, 1)

Comment: i even change the IMG_SIZE = 240 TO IMG_SIZE = 50

Comment: you have'nt given the input_shape to the VGG model. Initialize it with (50,50,3)

Comment: hiya sorry for the late reply i was running another code anyways i got this error :C ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (50, 50, 3) but got array with shape (50, 50, 1)